# Date and time format more than 24hrs

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm looking for a date and time format as per my below requirement:

Condition :
If time is less than 24hrs then format will be like 2h:56m:23s. If time exceeds from 24hrs it will be like 1d:15h:45m:8s

Here:
Time= Now() - AnypreviousDate

(Time will be calculated by subtracting two dates)

Please help with code of vb.net based on condition for 24hrs

Comment: That doesnt sound like a `DateTime` at all but rather a `TimeSpan`

Answer (score 0):

Possible options:

```vb
'using standard timespan format strings
Dim formattedTime = time.ToString("g")
```

Output: [Days] **1:15:45:08** -- [Hours] **2:56:23**

This option does not includes the tags for `d`, `h`, `m`, `s`.
However it does handle all of the formatting for you.

---

```vb
'using custom timespan format strings
Dim format as String = String.Empty

If time >= TimeSpan.FromDays(1) Then
    format = time.ToString("d\d\:hh\h\:mm\m\:ss\s")
Else
    format = time.ToString("hh\h\:mm\m\:ss\s")
End If
```

Output: [Days] **1d:15h:45m:08s** -- [Hours] **2h:56m:23s**

You can get more details on this format [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings)